# multiple Button in Android app

Tags: android, button

how can I make listener for multiple buttons in Android with for loop? Like in java :

```
private class Akcija implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        for(int r=0;r<brDugm;r++){
            if (e.getSource() == b[r]) {
                .... 
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int r=0;r<brDugm;r++)
{
    // Assuming b[r] is your button as object
    // Assuming your action has is a function in your class Currentclass
    b[r].addOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick()
        {
            Currentclass.this.actionOnClick();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should implement the interface `View.OnClickListener`, and override the `OnClick(View view)` method.

And then you do something like this:

`for ( int i=0;i<numButtons; i++ )
{ buttons[i].setOnClickListener(this);
}`

And in your `OnClick(View view)` method you implement your code.

Comment: I don't know if you can do this, but you could also create a single listener and set it to all your buttons, then you implement the `onClick(View)` method to do specific tasks depending on the `View` that generated the event (you can check which button generated the event by calling `getId()` from the `View` parameter)

Comment: I have made simple memory game in java, end I try to do the similar for android. In java all works... my game have image button, it would be much to create 20 single listener . In java I have done with simpe for loop, and work was the same like I create only one listener for one button